# In Perl, how can I make two passes over all the files specified on the command line via the diamond operator?

Tags: perl

If i have a text file and i want to run two types of operations, but each operation must read each line of the text separately from the other. The only way i know how to do it is

```
open out,(">>out.txt");
while (<>){
    #operation one
}
while (<>){
    #operation two
}
close out;
```

but this will run only on the first `while`, in which the operation runs fine, but the second one will not be complete because the second `while(<>)` does not actually re-read the file but tries to continue from where the first while left. Which is at the end of the file. So is there another way? Or is there a way to tell the second while to start again at the beginning?

Comment: close/re-open the file, or [rewind](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) it.

Comment: i cannot do that, after i  call from command line perl ex.pl text.txt i want to do all of this in one command

Comment: like I said, REWIND the file. that resets the file pointer to wherver you want, so you can continue reading from that point. e.g. first while leaves the pointer at the end of the file, so you rewind the beginning, and the second while starts reading as if the file has just been freshly opened.

Comment: @Kostas you are passing a filename `text.txt` store that in a variable, open a filehandle pointing to that filename and read from there instead of STDIN. Then you will be able to re-open the file as Marc B suggests.

Comment: i tried the rewind using seek out, 0, 0;  between the 2 whiles, it did not change anything, also @Hunter i do not know how to do what you said

Comment: what is the file you are reading from? the `out` file handle was opened with ">>" so this is a output file (not to be read)

Comment: @MiguelPrz it is a text document in the same directory is the .pl i call it from the command line, so i should use seek with whatever is the default name of the filehandle when called from stdin but i do not know what that is

Answer (score 4):

Given you mention in a comment:

```
 perl example.pl text.txt
```

The answer is - don't use `<>` and instead open a filehandle.

```
my ( $filename ) = @ARVG;

open ( my $input, "<", $filename ) or die $!;

while ( <$input> ) { 
    print; 
}

seek ( $input, 0, 0 ); 

while (  <$input> ) { 
    #something else
}
```

Alternatively, you can - assuming `test.txt` isn't particularly large - just read the whole thing into an array.

```
my @input_lines = <$input>;
foreach ( @input_lines ) { 
   #something
}
```

If you want to specify multiple files on the command line, you can wrap the whole thing in a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach my $filename ( @ARVG ) { 
    ## open; while; seek; while etc. 
}
```

Comment: Note: The `seeks` solution will fail if `<>` reads from something other than a plain file or a symlink to a plain file.

Answer (score 2):

If the data fits into memory:

```
my @lines = <>;

for ( @lines ){
  # operation one
}

for ( @lines ){
  # operation two
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to `local $/;`? Won't that slurp the whole file into one array element? Accessing the filehandle in a list context will slurp it using the `$/` record delimiter anyway.

Comment: @Sobrique: Oops. You are correct. Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you simply use the following?

```
while (<>) {
   operation1($_);
   operation2($_);
}
```

If not, then I'm assuming you need to process the content of all the files using one operation before it's process by the other.

`<>` reads from the files listed in `@ARGV`, removing them as it opens them, so the simplest solution is to backup `@ARGV` and repopulate it.

```
my @argv = @ARGV;
while (<>) { operation1($_); }
@ARGV = @argv;
while (<>) { operation2($_); }
```

Of course, it will fail if `<>` reads from something other than a plain file or a symlink to a plain file. (Same goes for any solution using `seek`.) The only to make that work would be to load the entire file into temporary storage (e.g. memory or a temporary file). The following is the simplest example of that:

```
my @lines = <>;
for (@lines) { operation1($_); }
for (@lines) { operation2($_); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can localize `@ARGV` before the first pass.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;


{
    local @ARGV = @ARGV;
    while (<>){
        print "Pass 1: $_";
    }
}

while (<>){
    print "Pass 2: $_";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If no file handle is used with the diamond operator, Perl will examine the `@ARGV` special variable. If `@ARGV` has no elements, then the diamond operator will read from `STDIN`.

This is other way of achieve your requirements:

```
my @stdin=<>;

foreach my $item( @stdin ) {
   # ...
}

foreach my $item( @stdin ) {
   # ...
}
```

Comment: i tried it, it did not change anything, program still ends after fist while.

Comment: @hymie yes, out is the result output, since i call the file i read as an argument in the command line, what is the right way to use seek?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the operation line by line, why not try something like this

```
sub operation_1 {
   my $line = shift;
   #processing for operation 1
}

sub operation_2 {
   my $line = shift;
   #processing for operation 2
} 

while(<>) {
   my $line = $_;
   chomp($line);
   operation_1($line);
   operation_2($line); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you were reading from an actual file, you could use

```
seek FILEHANDLE,0,0;
```

However, you are using `stdin` and I don't think that it's possible to rewind `stdin` and start over.

Comment: command goes like this, perl example.pl text.txt isn't there  a way?

Comment: @ikegami: if you want to answer the question, then answer the question yourself.  Please do not change every single word in the answer I gave.

Comment: This answer is full of fail :( `<>` is short for `<ARGV>`, not `<STDIN>`, and definitely not `<stdin>` (seeing as `stdin` doesn't even exist). As for "rewinding" `ARGV` (or `STDIN`), that's easy to test, and the result is that you can when it's a handle to a plain file.

Comment: The original question had no mention of using any arguments.  All he had was a perl script that called `<>` .  That's going to be `stdin` unless an argument is specifically passed, which (again) he did not say he was doing.  `stdin` is the accepted abbreviation of "standard input", and `STDIN` is the perl filehandle that points to `stdin`.  The answer was correct for the question as it was asked.  The fact that the question is wrong is not my fault.

Comment: Here is OP's own comment: "so i should use seek with whatever is the default name of the filehandle when called from stdin".

Comment: The "default name", like I said, is `ARGV`. There is no variable named `stdin` (though there is one named `STDIN`). You're the first to mention `stdin`. You apparently don't know the meaning of the word abbreviation, and `STDIN` doesn't "point to" or otherwise use C's `stdin`.

Comment: You have absolutely no idea what you are talking about.  The default for `<>` may be `@ARGV`, but also by default, there is no `@ARGV` unless the program is called with arguments.  Since the OP did not mention any arguments, that is the reason I "first mentioned" `stdin`, although it was later confirmed by the OP. `STDIN` is not a variable, it is a special filehandle.  `stdin` is not C's, it is a generic computer term used by all programs and features of Unix (and Windows) to represent standard input, just like `stdout` and `stderr`.